# Impossible to use middlewares with Firebase and NuxtJS 3

Tags: javascript, firebase, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I'm trying to use Firebase authentication on an example project. Authentication is working as expected, but as soon as I want to use middlewares to prevent users from accessing admin pages or to access login page whereas already logged in, it's impossible.

I have been trying for hours, but nothing worked.

Here is my `package.json`:

```json
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nuxt": "3.0.0-rc.6"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^9.9.2"
  }
}
```

My `App.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <NuxtPage />
  </div>
</template>
```

My folders:

```
app.vue
nuxt.config.ts
package.json
...
pages/
-- index.vue
-- login.vue
-- register.vue
composables/
-- useFirebase.ts
-- useFirebaseUser.ts
plugins/
-- firebase.client.ts
```

`useFirebase.ts` only contains Firebase functions.

`useFirebaseUser` here:

```js
import type {User} from "firebase/auth";

export const useFirebaseUser = (init?:User|null) => useState<User|null>("user", () => init ?? null);
```

Now my `firebase.client.ts` plugin:

```js
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { onAuthStateChanged, getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

export default defineNuxtPlugin(async (nuxtApp) => {
    const firebaseConfig = {
        // ...
    };

    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    const auth = getAuth(app);
    const firebaseUser = useFirebaseUser(auth.currentUser);
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
        console.log("auth state changed =", user);
        firebaseUser.value = user;
    });
});
```

I have tried to use `addRouteMiddleware` within the plugin but then the page that uses it says it doesn't exist...

I have tried to declare a middleware in `middleware` directory and to use `getAuth()` from Firebase, but it says no Firebase app was initialized. I think the plugins are being loaded after the middlewares.

I have tried to provide a variable via:

```js
return {
 provide: { auth: () => getAuth(app) }
}
```

At the end of the plugin, but it says "$auth" is not a function when I access it in the middleware via `useNuxtApp`.

I also tried:

```js
nuxtApp.provide("auth", getAuth(app))
```

Which simply doesn't work as `getAuth().currentUser` gets its value once `onAuthStateChanged` was executed, after the page was loaded, making it useless because it will always give `null` or `undefined`.

Does someone know a magic way to use middlewares with Firebase authentication?