# How to abort navigation to a page with NuxtJS 3?

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I wanna check whether a user is authenticated or not so that he can access a page. If he is not, then I want to redirect him.

Here is my code `login.vue` page:

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
const router = useRouter();
const user = useFirebaseUser();
if (user.value != null) {
  router.back(); // raising an error
}

interface State {
  email: string;
  password: string;
}

const state: State = reactive({
  email: "",
  password: "",
});

async function signIn() {
  try {
    await signInUser(state.email, state.password);
    router.replace("/"); // works
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <NuxtLink to="/"><button>go back</button></NuxtLink>
    <h1>Login in</h1>
    <form @submit.prevent="signIn">
      <input v-model="state.email" type="email" />
      <input v-model="state.password" type="password" />
      <button type="submit">log in</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>
```

Calling `router.back()` (or `router.replace('/')`) throws the following exception:

```
runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:10 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node.
    at insert (http://localhost:3000/_nuxt/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-DPG7LVJ7.js?v=cf5cb64f:7255:12)
    at move (http://localhost:3000/_nuxt/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-DPG7LVJ7.js?v=cf5cb64f:5889:9)
    at move (http://localhost:3000/_nuxt/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-DPG7LVJ7.js?v=cf5cb64f:5862:7)
    at activeBranch.transition.afterLeave (http://localhost:3000/_nuxt/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-DPG7LVJ7.js?v=cf5cb64f:2313:15)
    at performRemove (http://localhost:3000/_nuxt/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-DPG7LVJ7.js?v=cf5cb64f:5976:20)
    at el._leaveCb (http://localhost:3000/_nuxt/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-DPG7LVJ7.js?v=cf5cb64f:2950:9)
    at finishLeave (http://localhost:3000/_nuxt/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-DPG7LVJ7.js?v=cf5cb64f:7885:13)
    at resolve2 (http://localhost:3000/_nuxt/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-DPG7LVJ7.js?v=cf5cb64f:7916:30)
    at whenTransitionEnds (http://localhost:3000/_nuxt/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-DPG7LVJ7.js?v=cf5cb64f:8001:12)
    at http://localhost:3000/_nuxt/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-DPG7LVJ7.js?v=cf5cb64f:7927:11
```

Ideally, I'd like to use `middlewares` but it is [impossible with Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73261158/impossible-to-use-middlewares-with-firebase-and-nuxtjs-3).

Does someone know a way to redirect the user without using middleware?

Comment: Did you tried `await navigateTo`? https://v3.nuxtjs.org/api/utils/navigate-to

Comment: It doesn't change anything

Comment: What is `useFirebaseUser` doing? Is it populated at the given line?

Comment: `await navigateTo` works but if i go to the page by writing over the URL, it's ignored

Comment: `useFirebaseUser` is redefined in `onAuthStateChanged`

Comment: Probably because `setup` is too early in the lifecycle or something like that: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/lifecycle.html#lifecycle-diagram As for the second comment: whaat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247095/discussion-between-thomasg2201-and-kissu).